# First Chern Class $c_1$ of $O(1)$ Bundle over $\mathbb{CP}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, curvature

Let $\mathbb{CP}^n$ the complex projective space and $U_0:= \{[1: z_1:...:z_n] \in \mathbb{CP}^n 
\ \vert \ z_i \in \mathbb{C} \} \subset \mathbb{CP}^n$ a standard open subset wrt first cordinate.

Let $O(1) \to \mathbb{CP}^n$ the dual of the tautological line bundle: $O(1)= O(-1)^*$.

I have to show 
in an exercise that for the restriction of the first Chern class of $O(1)$ to $U_0$ this identity holds:

$$ c_1(O(1)) \vert _{[1:z_1:...:z_n]} =
-\frac{i}{2 \pi} \overline{\partial}
 \ \partial  \ log \|(1,z_1,...,z_n)\|^2 _{\mathbb{C}^{n+1}}$$

Here $\overline{\partial}, \partial$ are the Dolbeault operators and $\|(1,z_1,...,z_n)\|^2 = 1+ z \bar{z}$ the standard hermitian norm of $(1,z_1,...,z_n) \in \mathbb{C}^{n+1}$.

There is also following hint given: It is recommended to find a local holomorphic section
of the restricted tautological bundle $O(-1) \vert _{U_0} \to U_0$. The induced Riemann matric (the pullback metric) is also called Fubini Study metric.

I have no idea now to finish this proof. Can somebody help me?

What I have already done:

For Chern classes we have a nice identity: $c_1(O(1))= c_1(O(-1)^*)=(-1) \cdot c_1(O(-1))$
(I think it's useful here since the hint suggested to work with $O(-1)$.)

Keeping the hint in mind we choose a non vanishing section

$$s: \mathbb{C}^n \cong U_0 \to O(-1) \vert _{U_0}, 
[1:Z_1:...:Z_n] \mapsto ([1:Z_1:...:Z_n], k(z) \cdot (1,Z_1,...,Z_n))$$

with $k(z): U_0 \to \mathbb{C}^*$. I guess that maybe that one with $k(z)=1$ does the job...

Since over $U_0$ that's an diffeomorphism and the Fubini Study metric is compatible with
standard hermitian metric $h: \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^n \to \mathbb{C}^n$ we obtain
the pullback metric $g:= s^* h$ on $O(-1) \vert _{U_0}$.

Next, the first Chern class coinsides up
to a constant with the curvature $\Omega^{O(-1)}$ (a $(1,1)$-form) induced by connection 
$(\nabla^{O(-1)})$:

$c_1(O(-1)) =\frac{\Omega^{O(-1)}}{2 \pi i}
=\frac{(\nabla^{O(-1)})^2}{2 \pi i}$

Locally the connection $\nabla^{O(-1)}=$ has structure $d+ \theta$ where $d= \partial
+ \overline{\partial}$ is the 
differential and $\theta $ a $(1,0)$-form on $U_0$. 
That's a basic fact that locally the curvature has structure

$\Omega^{O(-1)}= (\nabla^{O(-1)})^2= d \theta + \theta \wedge \theta$.

and we need to show

$$d \theta + \theta \wedge \theta =\overline{\partial}
\partial log \|(1,z_1,...,z_n)\|^2 $$

From here I haven't any idea how to continue the proof. Could somebody help me how to show this claim?
How are $\theta$ and section $s$ related to each other?

Comment: Note that $\theta$ is a scalar-valued $1$-form (why?), so $\theta\wedge\theta = 0$. Now how is $\theta$ related to $\partial \log h$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Hi, that's because we learned general fact that locally a connection of a vector bundle $E \to M$ can be described as $d + \theta$ where $\theta$ is as you said a $1$-form with coefficients in $\operatorname{End} E$. In our case the bundle in a line bundle, so $\operatorname{End}$ is fiberwise scalar value. That is the answer to your why? Or did you intend to adress another issue by the (why?)? About you second question I'm not sure. locally, $h(s,t)= s^t H \bar{t}$ with Hermitian matrix $H$. And $\partial \log h= \frac{\partial h}{h}$.

Comment: Locally we have $\frac{s^t (\partial H) \bar{t}}{s^t H \bar{t}}$. I don't kno how to relate it to $\theta$

Comment: (probably this exactly the key point)
 we know $d= \partial + \overline{\partial}$ and $\partial^2=0$. Therefore the goal is to prove $\theta= \partial \log h= \frac{\partial h}{h}$ but I don't know how to manage the first equality

Comment: Look specifically at how what's usually called the Chern connection is defined on a hermitian vector bundle.

Comment: I still haven't elaborated out this argument but I guess I slowly understand in which direction the wind is blowing. The Chern class are independent of the choice of a connection thus we can probably exploit it and choose this Chern connection as the connection we are working  with. What I found is that it exists for every hermitian holomorphic bundle $E \to M$ and has structure $\nabla^{Chern}=\nabla^{1,0} + \overline{\partial}^E= Proj^{1,0} \circ \nabla +\overline{\partial}^E$ for arbitrary connection $\nabla $ (it seems to be a non trivial result that it is indeed independent of $\nabla$).

Comment: I still have to think carefully about it's local structure $\nabla^{Chern}= d + \theta^{Chern}$ but I guess that was exactly your hint, right? that $\theta^{Chern}= \frac{\partial h}{h}$?

Comment: @TedShifrin: Hi, a little update: I searched for the properties of this "Chern connection" and found some stuff on it's distinguished role I sketched in comments above but nowhere explanations on it's local structure $d + \theta$ (especially what spacial form has $\theta$. I guess that it's exactly what we are looking for (ie $\theta=  \frac{\partial h}{h}$) but that's only my suspicion. Could you recommend a source dealing with the local structure of this Chern connection?

Comment: Any book on complex manifolds covers this material. Chern's own book (*Complex Manifolds without Potential Theory*), Griffiths & Harris (*Principles of Algebraic Geometry*), Wells (*Differential Analysis on Complex Manifolds*), and the newer texts by Huybrechts and DeMailly.

Comment: Thank you a lot!